# Send info to google tag manager from backend

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-api, google-tag-manager

Working on a website, I use Google Tag Manager and push some info with the dataLayer in Javascript. So far so good. However there are some information that should not be seen on the client side. Therefore I'm wondering if it's possible to do the same thing on the backend?

Basically a request to GTM API that does the equivalent of

```
dataLayer.push({
    'event': 'transaction',
    'something': {
        'superSecret': 42
    }
});
```

but on backend. (I've never used GTM API and I'm not sure if it permits to do this kind of requests. If possible, I would appreciate some help :) ). Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

GTM for the Web is basically a Javascript injector - the Interface is there to configure your tags, then everything is wrapped into a JavaScript function that is inserted into your page and executed by the browser. There is no serverside component that you could push data to.

So quite probably the answer is no (unless you want to try really weird workarounds like running the container in a headless browser on your server or trying to abuse the mobile SDKs for GTM, which works rather differently than the web version). I guess it would be easier to send your serverside calls directly to the respective tracking services.

**Updated 07/20201** [Server-side GTM](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside) has moved out of beta a few months ago, so now you can run a container in a virtual machine that proxies tracking requests to tracking vendors. You can hit the endpoint for server-side GTM from your backend (basically with anything that sends http requests), so by now server-side GTM is the way to go for what you asked for. Technically it's a different beast that client-side GTM, but Google did a very good job at making the interface look and feel familiar.

Comment: Why do we need a container? How can I simply replicate the send HTTP event from the client in the backend?

Comment: You do not need a container. The container is a convenience and gives you an interface that is programmable in Javascript, and templates (both built-in and provided in the template gallery) save you the work of re-engineering the request. format for popular marketing tags. But if you do not require a generic solution with a user interface, you can absolutely send requests via your own backend. A number of vendors also offer documented server-to-server integrations. Basically since the question was tagged "GTM", I answered it in the context of GTM.

Answer (score 0):

In 2020 Google has released Google Tag Manager for server-side tracking, where you run a container in a cloud environment that then distributes the requests.
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/serverside

Facebook and Google Analytics Support this now. So you can move tracking to server side.