# Send dataLayer variables to GTM from backend post callback

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, payment-gateway, google-tag-manager

Some GTM wisdom needed.

We use measure protocol to send some transactions to Google Analytics & using GTM too in "thank you page". We are not happy with that.

Is there a way we can send Data Layer Variables from backend using some GTM call? I want to know how you solve that using GTM & dataLayer

My first idea is to try emulate measure protocol using something similar to  https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-for-devices-without-javascript-support

Context: Some payment methods notify transactions to my backend system via a background HTTP post method call from their backend system, not an interactive browser (where server-side code do the measure protocol request)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39774009/send-info-to-google-tag-manager-from-backend/39774360#39774360; with GTM for web there is no  backend to send calls to. There might be workarounds, but I am not sure what would be gained compared to send requests via the measurement protocol.

Comment: For example, remarketing tags only fire from GTM.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add more clearance into terminology you are using.

1. Measurement protocol is HTTP request to `google-analytics.com` containing all `key=value` pairs in its query string or in POST data.
   [Use documentation on Goodle Developers](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters). This is direct input into Google Analytics.
2. DataLayer is usualy JavaScript object containing `key : value pairs` [Check documentation here](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/reference). This keys are then accessible in GTM interface to be paired with pre-prepared TAGs in their particular fields. In case of non-javascript solution are these parameters translated into Image Request and sended in different way to Google Analytics.
3. [Adding variables for devices without JavaScript](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-for-devices-without-javascript-support) is about specifying JS dataLayer object in [flatten](https://gist.github.com/penguinboy/762197) mode like GET parameters. This mean you do not emulate Measurement protocol, you "simulate" dataLayer.

### My suggestion:

If you have your GTM setted in standard manners (by Google Documentation), then use "[Adding Data Layer Variables for Devices without JavaScript Support](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#adding-data-layer-variables-for-devices-without-javascript-support)" and it will save you a lot of time.

If you are using custom JavaScript implementations, do it with Measurement Protocol by Image Request.

Comment: These means that my server side code can do a get request to the GTM url as I do for Measure Protocol?

Comment: @jrosell I am not sure if you can do GTM call from server side. What you definitely can do is Measurement Protocol request from server to google server. I think (I am not sure in this) if you make iframe GTM call, it is processed in that iframe via HTML components. I would like to test it, but I do not have time for it now.

Comment: The GET request to the URL within the <iframe> simply fetches an HTML page from Google's servers. On that page are any (supported) tags that you might have configured, and they can grab key-value pairs from query parameters in the URL. 

So you still need a web client (e.g. headless browser) to render the elements in the iframe, so that they are fired as pixel requests to their respective endpoints. Thus there's no direct server-to-server call like Measurement Protocol for Google Tag Manager.